# не получается найти элемент на странице при помощи Selenium

Tags: python, парсер, selenium-webdriver

код

```
import time 
import selenium 
 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

while True: 
    time.sleep(1) 
    content = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, '.text-grey-2') 
    print(content.text)
```

[image]

он пытается найти это но не получается.

ошибка:

[image]

Я искал по разному и при помощи CSS_SELECTOR и XPATH но всё не получается хотя эта строка на сайте есть которую я ищу

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: точку перед `text-grey-2` уберите

Comment: к сожалению не сработало

Comment: Что значить не сработало? Какую ошибку выдает сейчас?

Comment: http://pastie.org/p/17pMimQDZ54ZUQnDbb3ix7

только почему то в коде ошибки он пытается найти ".text-grey-2"
хотя в коде "text-grey-2"

Comment: Попробуйте добавить тайм-аут - "когда элемент станет видимым на веб-странице". https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html. Может одной секунды задержки маловато.

Comment: И уберите пока цикл while, найдите хотя бы один элемент.

Comment: я пытался кнопку найти не получилось такое ощущение что там вообще ничего не получится найти

Comment: Да, похоже, что вы потерялись. Возьмите для начала сайт попроще.

Comment: спасибо за помощь